# How to refresh the result of getservbyname() function?

Tags: c, linux, unix, system-calls, network-service

I configured the following in my `/etc/services/` file:

```
tt16       9898/tcp
```

and then called the `getservbyname()` and got port number as `9898` (after `ntohs()`).

I then changed the port number for the name as:

```
tt16       9900/tcp
```

But still the function `getservbyname()` returned the port `9898` instead of `9900`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you restart the application between the two calls to `getservbyname()`.

Comment: `endservent()` might help, but you probably shouldn't do this at all. `/etc/services` isn't really a configuration file where you store local oddities. Think of it as containing facts about the world, not about the local machine.

Comment: alk: yes I restarted the application, but still the same behavior. Do I have to restart the system.   Wumpus: if one wants to store a port name(local to the system), then is their any other configuration file also present

Comment: @user3363754: It might be interesting to know if restarting the system helps, just to narrow down the issue. Generally there should be no reason to restart the system for this. Testing whether `endservent()` helps, as per *Wumpus*'s comment, I'd also suggest.